React-Native expo build fail
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\UserApp\UserApp\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\8.3\scripts\5j7g1j6r4x8ze3vgdjetfvry4).


BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'BuildScript' Unsupported class file major version 66


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

I've been having problem while trying to run, npx expo run:android, and I couldn't find anything that solves the problem!! Please help me.
I've reinstalled the new Java 22, reinstalled the Android Studio, and still didn't solve the problem.
